# How to fix or replace the timer button of a microwave oven?

Tags: repair, microwave-oven

I have a microwave oven which timer button is broken. I would like to fix it (by using glue?) or replace it (with a similar "key"). The oven is a Samsung M1714.

However, I am afraid of making things worse if I try to repair it, and I do not know any shop where I could buy something similar. I noticed there is the number 3 written on the inside of the broken piece.

[image: Looking at the oven, with and without the button]
[image: Looking at the connection on both sides]

Do you know an online shop for this kind of thing?

Here are several shots:
[image: Looking at the place where there should be a button]
[image: Looking at the button side which is usually not visible]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have repaired dials similar to this in the past.

I have found that if you apply some CA glue (super glue) or epoxy to the crack, and then wrap the outside of the shaft tightly with electrical tape, it will hold up under most circumstances.

Failing that, it appears that you can buy the replacement knob from [several online suppliers](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&sugexp=ldymls&xhr=t&q=Samsung+M1714+control+knob&cp=26&qe=U2Ftc3VuZyBNMTcxNCBjb250cm9sIGtub2I&qesig=CQBsar9oDR247EOnvpIaLQ&pkc=AFgZ2tn1YtjVNN2g38sh_SA1RtEX44xo2gkV9qC1U8Zcdi7neSnCBnP6GEQgCSe7B8nZHiv4cQ32t-8FmN-GiL2h3yIwo_l9PQ&pf=p&sclient=psy&safe=active&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=Samsung+M1714+control+knob&pbx=1&fp=72460827cd13960a).

Comment: A small metal hose clamp may work after using glue .  But seriously, get a new knob, that one looks like it is toast!!!!!!!!

Comment: Up-voted this answer because of the hose-clamp idea in the comment above - exactly what I was thinking.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually repair this knob with resin + fiberglas. You can see the final result here.

[image]

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: HI 3dfroggy. We appreciate your answer but this question has already been answered February 2011 with a very similar answer. You could have improved the answer by adding photos directly in your post instead of providing links. Welcome to DIY but please familiarise yourself with the rules and possibly click on meta right at the top to ask moderators for more help.

Comment: I like this answer.